# How to show ascii non-printable characters in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ascii, visual-studio-code, non-printing-characters

I'm using Visual Studio Code version 1.51.1 and am wondering if there is any way to display all of the ascii non-printable characters when looking at a file. I used to use Notepad++ and it had a feature you could turn on that would show every character in a file including non-printable characters.

For example, here's a screenshot from a file open in Notepad++ that I've inserted the non-printable `BEL` character in by pressing `ALT + 007`. You can also see the carriage-return/line feeds at the end of the line:

[image]

Here's a list of the characters I'm referring to ([I found this list here](http://www.asciitable.com/)):

[image]

So what I'm asking is there an extension I can install into Visual Studio Code or a setting that I can configure that will show all ascii characters, both printable and non-printable, similar to how Notepad++ does it as shown in the screenshot I provided? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the bottom-right corner of the status bar, you will see the encoding of the file. Click and select “Reopen with Encoding…” and change to something like UTF-8 or higher.

You can also search for the “Change File Encoding” task via Cmd+Shift+P.

Comment: looks like that worked, thank you for answering such an old question. upvoted and marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Hex Editor extension is a good option. [image: Hex Editor data inspector].